# macOS : Monitor Application CPU load from within

Tags: macos, performance, foundation, mach

I've developed an executable mach-o from which I can spawn a process that can exceed CPU utilization to above threshold that trigger the spindump analysis. This inspection is very time consuming and potential may halt threads that wait for kernel response, so I'd like to avoid it.

Therefore, I wish to find an accurate way to measure my process contribution to the CPU load on a separate thread, and upon exceeding some threshold for pre-defined amount of time, it will trigger temporal cool down of my user-space process.

I just found out that `top` uses `task_info` to send mach port message to get this information. Perhaps anyone did some research about to properly use this method in order to get the equivalent for `%CPU` in my own process ?

Notice that my executable doesn't based on Cocoa so it doesn't have `NSRunLoop` but it's C++/Objective-C/Swift mixture project, so I can use any `Foundation.framework`.